# Synchronize IIS web server configurations

Tags: c#, iis, web

We have multiple load balanced IIS web servers for our application backed by a MS SQL server database. We store application configuration information in the database. While the application is running I frequently change the configuration and the changes need to be propagated to the other web servers. Is there a good way to do this? I have been doing it through SignalR (to alert other servers a change has occurred and they should refresh their configuration) but SignalR is not always reliable and sometimes one server does not get the message.  Is there a better solution?

Thank you

Comment: have you tried Node.Js + Socket.IO?

Comment: @vishwaratna Any reason you'd recommend a completely different tech stack over SignalR, which effectively does the same thing within the existing tech stack?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

I now understand you to need to propagate an *application level* configuration change.

You could, as you mentioned, use SignalR. This would require having a *central* server that hosts the websocket connections, but has the benefit of being "instant".

Alternatively, if your requirements are simple, perhaps a short term in-memory cache would suffice.

If it's complex than that, I'd recommend looking into event queues (MSMQ, RabbitMQ). In this model, the instance changing the configuration publishes an event to the queue which can be consumed by the other instances on a background thread.

**Original Answer**

[Microsoft Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy) was built to do this. It supports synchronizing sites across servers, even down to application pool settings and SSL certificates.

The IIS documentation site has a specific page that is relevant to your use case: [Synchronize IIS](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/synchronize-iis).

There is a lot involved in configuring Web Deploy so I won't attempt to explain it all here, but for posterity reasons the command to sync a local site to a remote machine would be:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync 
             -source:apphostconfig="Default Web Site" 
             -dest:apphostconfig="Default Web Site",computername=Server1
```

*(The command was split over multiple lines for readability)*

As an an entirely alternative approach, you could also use a "pull configuration" system like [Powershell Desired State Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/overview) or [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/).

Comment: If I understand properly, this would be to synchronize the initial server/IIS configuration which is not a problem at the moment (although I will need to look into down the road).  My problem right now is a user changes a configuration (which is stored in the database) and the server that received the change is aware of the change but I need to alert the other web servers of the configuration change (without restarting IIS)

Comment: @jwerfel Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response @richard-szalay, for now I think I will stick with SignalR since we only have a few web servers but I'll look into using more advanced even queues.